# Clang Xcode wrapper produce 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]

Tags: swift, xcode, clang

I made a 'SizeOptimizer' swift script project to intercept Xcode compiler commands (just clang, not swiftc). Basically it looks like this:

```
    let arguments = CommandLine.arguments
    let task = Process()
    task.launchPath = "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang"
    task.arguments = arguments
    task.launch()
    task.waitUntilExit()
```

I added the SizeOptimizer binary as my custom clang compiler in Xcode like this:
[image]

With that, when I build the project, Xcode will use 'SizeOptimizer' instead of 'clang'

Old:
[image]
New:
[image]

But the problem is that 'SizeOptimizer' is generating:

```sh
clang: warning: /Users/luis.gomez/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SizeOptimizer-bqegltybchfyoxdanpdkoqifnmgi/Build/Products/Debug/SizeOptimizer: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
```

[image]

So, what am I doing wrong? at the moment I'm just passing the arguments to clang as they come.

Note: The build is successful, but I want to fix these ugly warnings.

Thanks!